# In angular 7 how can I convert app page to PDF?

Tags: angular, pdf-generation

After my user fills out the form I want to render the page to PDF.

There are a lot of options for HTML to PDF, how would I render the page in memory and get the innerHtml? Or is there another way?

Right now I'm building the PDF manually.

Comment: Can you share some of your code with us? What have you tried?

Comment: Not sure if it's your case, but looks same for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55019343/how-to-generate-a-pdf-using-angular-7

Comment: http://pdfmake.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jspdf and html2canvas

install this package.

```
npm i jspdf
npm i html2canvas
```

ts file

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import h2c from 'html2canvas';

loadPDF() {
let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
h2c(document.getElementById('pagePrintPdf')).then(function (canvas) {
  let width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
  let height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
  let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
  doc.addImage(dataURL, 'jpg', 0, 0, width, height, 'none');
  doc.save(`test.pdf`);
  });
}
```